# "invaiid operands to binary *" when assigning to uint* after g_malloc()

Tags: c, casting, glib

I have the following code segment

```
...
params->running = g_malloc(sizeof(*params->running))
*(params->running) = loopcount;
...
```

params looks like this

```
struct TaskParams                                                                                                              
{               
    ...
    unsigned int    *running;                                                                                                      
};
```

I am expecting g_malloc to return a gpointer (void*) that is implicitly cast to unsigned int * and that i can assign that with `*params->running = some_unit_value`

I get an error however on the line `*(params->running) = loopcount;`

```
error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘gpointer’ and ‘unsigned int *’)
```

and I don't get it. gpointer is void* and that should be cast implicitly right? What am I missing here?

Comment: On *what line* do you get the error?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Edited for clarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 error: invalid operands to binary *
                            ^^^^^^
```

Obviously you're trying to use a *unary* operator, so what the heck is going on?

Well, you forgot the semicolon `;` from the end of the previous line...

Comment: Well, that was kind of embarrassing. Thanks.